# Overrride classes in a spring boot application, with classes from external jar files

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, classloader

How can I, with a boot application, let classes located in an external jar-file override classes in my boot application?

**Use case**: A boot application `largeApp` is released infrequently. As a user of `largeApp` I want to correct bugs by overriding specific classes without rebuilding `largeApp`.

```
  .
  |-- dist
  |   |-- largeApp.jar
  |   |-- lib
  |   |   `-- bugfixes.jar
```

---

**EDIT**: Bean overriding is too narrow of a scope.

Before switching to boot, I solved this by building `myApp` to include `largeApp`

- Using war projects, `myApp.war` and `largeApp.war`

  ```
  <project>
    <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
            <artifactId>largeApp</artifactId>
            <version>${fw.commons.jetty.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </project>
  ```
- Both project would contain `src/main/java/SomeClass.java` and the class from `myApp` was automatically loaded first (since war classloader first loads project class files, then jar-files)

---

**EDIT 2**:

- Service classes are spring managed and could possibly be overriden as beans
- Some classes are created by constructor `new Foo()`
- Some classes are created by reflection `Class.forName("a.b.Foo")`

Also, configuration management is not an issue.

Comment: Is it beans overriding you are talking about?

Comment: What if you will have multiple fixes of the same bean?

Comment: If you really must do something like that - create patcher that will modify content of largeApp.jar and will replace class files. Its a zip after all.

Comment: From a configuration management perspective this is a terrible idea and should be avoided.

Comment: Is it possible to extend the SomeClass? As a spring user, I think it's a good practice to use dependency injection to inject a fixed version of SomeClass (maybe SomeClassFixed).

From my perspective, it's not a good idea to have same classes in the classpath, we can't expect different classloader will load the class with same order.

Comment: Adapt classloader to become predictable is an option. Extending a class can be done, but not all classes are created as beans or by dependency injection.